# Output parameter issue in a Store procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I have 2 table's `Customer` and `Beneficiary`. There are 2 or more Beneficiary added with a single Customer Mobile number.
I have Created a Stored proc to get the Beneficiary name related to that Mobile Number

```
create Proc Customer
(
@Mobile bigint,

@Beneficiary  varchar(100) out,

@Beneficiary2 varchar(100) out  
)
as

Begin

Select @Beneficiary = Beneficiary_Name, @Beneficiary2 = Beneficairy_Name from Beneficiary_master
as a 

join Customer_Master as b
on a.CustomerID= b.CustomerID

where Mobile_Number = @Mobile

End

Declare @Beneficiary varchar(100)

Declare @Beneficiary2 varchar(100)

Exec spCustomer 999999999, @Beneficiary out, @beneficiary2 out
```

How to get both the Beneficiary Names, as i am getting only 1 name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Select Query will return the record(s) matching the select statement, and will assign the result of the last record to the variables `@Beneficiary` and `@Beneficiary2`

You have to change the select query to get the desired o/p. Please have a try on this statement, and if suit's your requirement make change in SP accordingly

```
Declare  @Mobile bigint =123

Declare @Beneficiary  varchar(100) 

Declare @Beneficiary2 varchar(100) 

Select @Beneficiary = Beneficiary_Name 
from Beneficiary_master as a 
join Customer_Master as b on a.CustomerID= b.CustomerID
where Mobile_Number = @Mobile
ORDER BY Beneficiary_Name ASC
OFFSET  0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

Select @Beneficiary2 = Beneficiary_Name 
from Beneficiary_master as a 
join Customer_Master as b on a.CustomerID= b.CustomerID
where Mobile_Number = @Mobile
ORDER BY Beneficiary_Name ASC
OFFSET  1 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

Select @Beneficiary Beneficiary, @Beneficiary2 Beneficiary2
```

Comment: If your issue got resolved with this solution, Please mark this as useful, or accept the answer. So that other person who have the same issue can try out this solution with confidence